# How can I move a view from one feature to another?

Tags: 7, views, features

I have a view that I added to Feature A that I would instead like to move to Feature B.  I re-created Feature A using the admin interface, but even after re-creating the feature, clearing the cache, and reverting the feature, the view still appears in the database in code and I am unable to attach it to Feature B.

How can I remove a view from one feature and add it to another?

Comment: I just ran into this. When you re-create the Feature even if you remove (uncheck) the Views in the Features Admin. When Features rebuilds and exports the view -- if you simply overwrite the existing folder on your site the *.views.inc file will remain on the filesystem if you didn't delete the Feature folder first, and then upload the new feature. This is a subtle workflow issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling and then re-enabling the Feature A after you detach the view from it might solve this issue.

If you still can't attach the view to Feature B after you disabled and re-enabled Feature A, then you can export the view using the Views interface (not Features) copy the code to a text file, then delete the View by typing the URL to the delete page manually into the address bar (I assume Views UI won't give you a delete link because it will still assume it's coming from code). The delete page url is: admin/structure/views/view/**view_name**/delete

After that Import the view again through the Views UI and attach to Feature B.

I had a similar problem before, not exactly the same but similar issue with a certain element assuming it's coming from code after I detached it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried enabling and disabling the feature, but that didn't work.  Instead, based on your instructions, here's the path I took that worked. 1.) export the views 2.) disable Feature A 3.) manually delete the views include in Feature A which for some reason did not get deleted 4.) import the views 5.) add the views to Feature B 6.) re-enable Feature A

Comment: Glad it worked. I think it's a bug with the Features module, it's still Beta for D7 :(

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this by editing the respective view and causing the feature to go overridden.

Once the feature is overridden (aka. view settings/config saved in DB) we can recreate the respective feature w/o the view and drop that feature back into our site. Revert it, clear the cache (although when I did this, I didn't need to do either...still never a bad idea).

If all went according to plan you will now see the view is available to use in another feature, add it in, drop it back into your site and off you go!

This can also be done solely in code... 
Navigate to your feature module via the CLI, you will notice 2 files: .info and views_default.inc

Find the declaration in your .info file for the respective view and move it to the .info file of the feature you want it a part of.

Next you will want to find the section of code in the views_default.inc defining your view and move that to the views_default.inc file of your new feature. It will begin with `$view = new view();` and end with `$export['your_view'] = $view;`

You will want to revert your features to put the ordering correct in the files.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this issues is by cloning the from Feature A View. This will generate another UUID and Features B is going to be able to recognize the view.